# Ошибка в настроке VPS хостинга

Tags: php, vps

Всем привет. Перекинул из виртуального хостинга на VPS хостинг сайт, и он ругается на след. ошибку

```
if(isset($mysqlColumn[$cellPath]) and !empty($cell->getCalculatedValue()))
```

Ошибка

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in /var/www/www-root/data/www/reallot.kz/application/models/admin_model.php on line 124
```

Чувствую что проблема тут

```
empty($cell->getCalculatedValue()
```

empty аргументом можно передавать лишь переменную

Но на виртуальном хостинге работало все без проблем, в чем может быть причина

Comment: Проверьте версию php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> До PHP 5.5 empty() проверяет только переменные, и попытка проверить что-то еще вызовет ошибку синтаксиса. Другими словами, следующий код не будет работать: empty(trim($name)). Используйте вместо него trim($name) == false.

Старайтесь чаще читать [официальную документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) прежде чем задавать вопрос. В PHP она очень даже дружелюбна для новичка, т.к. содержит не только описание, но и массу всевозможных примеров.

В вашем конкретном случае проблема заключается в том, что вы перенесли скрипт на более низшую версию PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте просто `$cell->getCalculatedValue(). !empty`, по сути, это двойное отрицание